# Word ooxml difference between Mac and Windows

Tags: openxml, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

When attempting to get the ooxml from the document I've found a variance.

In Windows, iPad, and Word Online in a document that has a cross reference that will break if you update it, but is not yet broken. (Meaning if you right click it and press update then it will go to to the "Error! Reference source not found."  Then the xml will display the text value:

```
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF _Ref274197646 \n \h </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="39" w:name="_Read0190056i"/>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="40" w:name="_Read0190047i"/>
<w:r>
  <w:t>(i)</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="39"/>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="40"/>
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

However in the Mac even though the screen is displaying the text, the xml shows the broken reference text.

```
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:b/>
    <w:bCs/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>Error! Reference source not found.</w:t>
</w:r>
```

This feels like a bug, as the different versions of word should report the xml largely the same.

Comment: Sorry, couple of years late to the party, but a bug is not intentional coding that is inconsistent across versions. If code unintentionally leads to an incorrect result, or causes the software to behave in unintended ways, that's a bug.